# Razor code formatting issue with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, razor, resharper

With Visual Studio 2022 (across multiple minor/patch versions) and ReSharper 2021.3, I have a formatting issue with C# tags in Razor (.cshtml) views.

Given the following existing code:

[image: Before]

If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (format entire document), Visual Studio produces the following result:

[image: After]

The HTML tags formatting is fine, but the Razor tags formatting is a lot harder to read, especially for nested lambdas at the bottom.

I have tried different things, but I can't figure out the proper option in Visual Studio Settings or ReSharper Settings to manage these rules.

Comment: Re *"formatting issue"*: Can you [be](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70390496/edit) more specific in the question? What formatting issue? What C# tags (e.g., an example of such a tag and a line number)? It ought to be in the text.

Comment: What do you expect the formatting command to make the code look like? Are you expecting a setting in VS to work and it is not working as you expected, or are you just asking where to find the relevant formatting options in VS' settings menu?

Comment: The kbd shortcut mentioned by OP formats/indents all code in a given document, and it works well, the problem is that in these razor pages where we have html mixed with C# code, it does not work well, indentation gets all awkward, the above example is not that bad, it gets much worse.

Answer (score 1):

I postponed upgrading to .NET 6 because of this. It's definitely a bug and is not linked to ReSharper or .NET versions; it's the IDE itself.

You can see the bug report here on the developer community page:

*[VS 2022 Razor Editor not formatting HTML](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2022-razor-editor-not-formatting-html/1625350)*

And on GitHub:

*[VS 2022 Razor Editor not formatting HTML #8006](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8006)*

The issue was marked as stale due to lack of feedback by the author. New activity on the GitHub post with more relevant information about the bug may trigger a new investigation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just in case, even if your link does not mention .Net 6.0, for information I am using VS 2022, but still in .Net 5.0 for the project where I encounter this problem.